# Print out date (declared as a character) as a string

Tags: c, string, struct, char

i have this code that i need to print out the values without changing the char sizes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct studentData
{
int ID;
char lastName[10];
char firstName[10];
char birthMonth[2];
char birthDay[2];
char birthYear[4];
}
studentData;

int main()
{
 studentData admin={12345,"John","Doe","07","12","1990"};


printf("ID: %d\n",admin.ID);
printf("Last Name: %s\n",admin.lastName);
printf("First Name: %s\n",admin.firstName);
printf("Birth Month: %s\n",admin.birthMonth);
printf("Birth Day: %s\n",admin.birthDay);
printf("Birth Year: %s\n",admin.birthYear);

return 0;
}
```

my results

```
ID: 12345
Last Name: John
First Name: Doe
Birth Month: 07121990
Birth Day: 121990
Birth Year: 1990
```

What i want

```
ID: 12345
Last Name: John
First Name: Doe
Birth Month: 07
Birth Day: 12
Birth Year: 1990
```

I want to keep the Date as 2 bytes, month as 2 bytes so the \0 won't work here

Comment: What's the logic behind the %.2s\n

Answer (score 1):

Use a *precision* specifier with `"%s"` to not print more than the array size.  In this way `admin.birthMonth` does *not* need to be null character terminated.  Yet if code is later working with *strings*, using a [wider array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41249384/2410359) is judicious, only a tad memory expensive.

> the maximum number of bytes to be written for `s` conversions.  C11dr §7.21.6.1 4

```
printf("Birth Month: %.2s\n",admin.birthMonth);
// or
printf("Birth Month: %.*s\n", (int) (sizeof admin.birthMonth), admin.birthMonth);
```

Answer (score 0):

The assignment operation just fails to put a NULL character in the end for birthMonth, birthDay and birthYear because sizes of what you are trying to assign (i.e. "07", "12" or "1990") are same as sizes of the arrays (i.e. birthDay, birthMonth, birthYear). Make their corresponding array size atleast 1byte wider to make them able to contain a NULL-terminated string.

```
typedef struct studentData
{
    int ID;
    char lastName[10];
    char firstName[10];
    char birthMonth[3];
    char birthDay[3];
    char birthYear[5];
}
studentData;
```

As the size was exactly same as the size of what you want to assign, it fails to put a NULL in the end which results to printing Garbage characters.

**Or**

You can print using Precision Specifier i.e. by specifying how many characters you want to print like following

```
printf("Birth Month: %.2s\n", admin.birthMonth);
printf("Birth Day: %.2s\n", admin.birthDay);
printf("Birth Year: %.4s\n", admin.birthYear);
```

Look into [this](https://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output) to read more about Width & Precision Specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct studentData
{

    int ID;
    char lastName[10];
    char firstName[10];
    char birthMonth[3];
    char birthDay[3];
    char birthYear[5];

}

studentData;

int main()
{

    studentData admin={12345,"John","Doe","07","12","1990"};
    printf("ID: %d\n",admin.ID);
    printf("Last Name: %s\n",admin.lastName);
    printf("First Name: %s\n",admin.firstName);
    printf("Birth Month: %s\n",admin.birthMonth);
    printf("Birth Day: %s\n",admin.birthDay);
    printf("Birth Year: %s\n",admin.birthYear);
    return 0;

}
```

birthmonth, birthdate and birthyear should have size 3,3 & 5 so that the last space occupy the null character. In your code, the size is equal to the no. of character you want.
Thank You

Comment: If you got it TRUE them UPVOTE